# Facebook Insights API UserWarning: insights does not allow field

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook

I'm trying to get a list of all ad sets that I created in Facebook Ads. The pasted code was able to give me an expected output (except it wouldn't give me the conversion values). However, every time I run it, I will receive a message `UserWarning: insights does not allow field campaign_name warnings.warn(message)` on every fields.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Apologize for not referencing the code snippet...

```py
account = AdAccount('act_xxxxx')

def wait_for_async_job(async_job):
    async_job.api_get()
    while async_job[AdReportRun.Field.async_status] != 'Job Completed' or async_job[AdReportRun.Field.async_percent_completion] < 100:
        time.sleep(1)
        async_job.api_get()


params = {
    'time_range': {
        'since':  "2019-07-17",
        'until': "2019-07-23"
    },
    'fields': [
        AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.adset_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.adset_id,
        AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
        AdsInsights.Field.spend,
        AdsInsights.Field.conversion_values,
        AdsInsights.Field.clicks,
        AdsInsights.Field.action_values,
        AdsInsights.Field.purchase_roas
    ],
    'sort': [
        'date_start_ascending'
    ],
    'action_report_time': AdsInsights.ActionReportTime.impression,
    'level': AdsInsights.Level.adset,
    'time_increment': 1
}

async_job = account.get_insights_async(fields = params.get('fields'), params=params)
wait_for_async_job(async_job)
x = async_job.get_result(params={"limit": 25})
```

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @Paul, nope. I'm still having the issue. Although it seem safe to ignore, since it's still giving me the expected results, but I rather not have unwanted warnings in my code. Hope someone in the API team could clarify this.

Comment: Looks like FB have screwed the pooch with a recent API release. Perhaps it’s related. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/2388934868015239/